# Out result directly onto current screen field without C# etc

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way to output my SQL result directly to where screen cursor is currently. Example: If i execute "select 1" I want the result 1 to immediately populate where my cursor is (like a form fill). So if i place my cursor in an open notepad file, execute the query, it populates the 1 directly in as though "typed" in. I need to achieves this all through SQL query without C# or others.

Pretty sure many won't approve (if it's even possible) but i do have my reason for wanting to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

Long: I am sure you can't do this without using other programming languages.

The databases' purpose is to help application developers with storing and effectively retrieving data. So, it's kind of "utility for developers" which doesn't do anything useful without a separate (let's call it "front-end") program that inserts into and requests data from there.

My guess is you need a standalone program that wait for special key combination, asks db for data retrieval, detects active window and the element, and pastes data in there